# how do you backup iphone when some of the apps have the old style appleid?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, apple-id

i have an iphone 4s.  some of my apps where installed with my original apple id from years ago. at some point apple required/changed everyone to use email as their apple id.  Now when i try and back up my phone it asks for password, but it never succeeds because of the mismatched appleids. i cannot complete a backup in itunes.

anyone elese run into this issue?

Comment: what things  did you use the old if for?

Comment: You don't have the password of the old Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [HT201272 app store download ID incorrect (does not match settings ID)](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20085494#20085494)? (In short: Logout on your iPhone then re-sync via cable with iTunes)

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue before and the way I got it fixed was by resetting the password to the apple id.

Comment: but there are 2 appleids at play. the older not an email type and the new email